# Echo array value in different sections

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I want to echo a value of an array in a way that the first 4 would echo in a section and the rest (can be 5 or more) in a different section. For example:

```
<?php $items = $kStore->getItems(); ?>
    <div id="section1">
    <?php foreach($items as $item) { 
    if($count <= 4){
    ?>
    <h1><?php echo $item->getId(); ?></h1>
    <?php } }?>
    </div>

    <div id="section2">
    <?php foreach($items as $item) { 
    if($count > 4){
    ?>
    <h1><?php echo $item->getId(); ?></h1>
    <?php } } ?>
    </div>
```

I imagine it has to be something 'like that' but dont know how to get the count. Also, I don't want to go through the array twice, I feel it's not the fastest way to do it. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [array_slice](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to offset the start and limit the length of the section of the array you iterate over:

```
<div id="section1">
  <?php foreach(array_slice($items, 0, 4) as $item) { … } ?>
</div>
<div id="section2">
  <?php foreach(array_slice($items, 4) as $item) { … } ?>
</div>
```

#### Update

If `$items` is not an array, but merely a non-array object that implements [Iterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), you can't use this approach, but you can probably use [`LimitIterator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.limititerator.php) instead.

```
<?php
$sectionOneItems = new LimitIterator($items, 0, 4);
$sectionTwoItems = new LimitIterator($items, 4);
?>
<div id="section1">
  <?php foreach($sectionOneItems as $item) { … } ?>
</div>
<div id="section2">
  <?php foreach($sectionTwoItems as $item) { … } ?>
</div>
```

If this, too, does not work, then some more introspection of the object being iterated over is required.

Comment: It's not working with my code. I guess my $items variable is not an array but it's getting it from an object (array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array)

Comment: @raygo that's possible, but what does happen when you try the above code?

Comment: I get the error array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array. If I just do a foreach ($items as $item){ echo $item->getId(); } I get a result

Comment: @raygo OK, what are the keys? Try `foreach ($items as $k => $v) { var_dump($k); }`. If they're numeric, you have a built-in counter.

Answer (score 0):

i think this function might be useful for you
array_chunk ().http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php